# Sudden self signed certificte problem in multiple environments

Tags: laravel, curl, certificate

I am using Laravel and am trying to send email using Mailgun and Laravel's native Mailable class. The emails are generated as a result of submitting one of several forms.  I have been developing my features for a couple of days, and have successfully been receiving emails from my local machine (using homestead) throughout this time.

I have uploaded my code to a server, tested the forms, and everything is still good.  Additionally, a colleague of mine has downloaded the code and tests are still successful.  So in short, 2 local homestead environments and one ubuntu server are all working as expected.

Suddenly, this functionality has stopped working in all three environments. Upon submitting any form, I get the following error message:

```
GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ RequestException
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in
certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

This has started happening without any changes being made to the code, and is happening on both the local environments and the server - all at the same time.

I have absolutely no idea what could cause this.  Is this mail related and something to do with Mailgun?  Is this really a certificate issue and maybe something to do with a corporate certificate that allows traffic to leave the network? I am at a loss.

Is anyone able to offer any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check mailgun account domain settings? You can verify the DNS etc Under Domain Verification & DNS select Check DNS Records Now. If nothing flags as an issue I would suspect its a TLS issue or your guzzle uses a old SSL version possibly. Updating composer may help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a good night's sleep, I returned this morning and found all my forms working again. I have no idea what the problem was, but it seems to be a problem with an external service, not my setup.

Thanks